# Origin of square-and-multiply algorithm

Tags: ho.history-overview, algorithms

I'm teaching an introductory course in cryptography and explained the square-and-multiply algorithm to the class.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-and-multiply_algorithm

Someone asked who discovered the algorithm, which I didn't know, so after a short web search that gave no answers, I thought I'd ask on MO. In particular, the above wikipedia article is not helpful, and I didn't see any MO questions that address the issue. This seems like something that Gauss and Euler, or even Fermat, might have known, and ditto for Indian and Chinese mathematicians centuries earlier, but I'm just speculating. Specific references would be appreciated. (Sorry if this isn't really a research level question, although maybe it qualifies as historical research.)

Comment: The logarithmic version of square-and-multiply is essentially what is often called the Russian peasant method for multiplying integers. This was already used in ancient times by Egyptians and Babylonians.

Comment: @Franz: Thanks. Do you have a reference? And by "log version", do you mean double-and-add?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This method is indeed over 2000 years old. The history, with references, is discussed by Donald Knuth in *Seminumerical Algorithms,* volume 2 of *The Art of Computer Programming*, page 441:

> The method is quite ancient; it
>   appeared before 200 B.C. in Pingala's
>   Hindu classic Chandah-sutra [see B.
>   Datta and A.N. Singh, *History of Hindu
>   Mathematics* 1, 1935]; however, there
>   seem to be no other references to this
>   method outside of India during the
>   next 1000 years. A clear discussion of
>   how to compute $2^n$ efficiently for
>   arbitrary $n$ was given by al-Uqlidisi
>   of Damscus in 952 A.D.; see *The
>   Arithmetic of al-Uglidisi* by A.S.
>   Saidan (1975), p. 341-342, where the
>   general ideas are illustrated for
>   $n=51$. See also al-Biruni's
>   *Chronology of Ancient Nations* (1879),
>   p. 132-136; this eleventh-century
>   Arabic work had great influence.

For a detailed discussion of the earliest history, see A. Kulkarni, [Recursion and Combinatorial Mathematics in Chandashaastra](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703658). [Chandashaastra = Chandah-sutra]

Comment: Is this for square-and-multiply or double-and-add
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication)?
I thought that the Legendre formula $a^{(p-1)/2} \bmod p$
was originally thought impractical for lack of square-and-multiply.
Note that the "mod $p$" part is essential, otherwise $a^n$ soon
becomes so large that writing out $a^n$ in full becomes infeasible
in any case.

Comment: this is the binary method for exponentiation, which is what is called the "square and multiply" method.

Comment: To be clear, square for even exponents, square and multiply one more for an odd exponent.   Gerhard "Or Some Other Variation Thereupon" Paseman, 2012.09.20

Comment: @Carlo: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for.

Comment: But is Chandah-sutra open access?